# ellipse in haskell CodeWorld

Tags: haskell, codeworld

Can anyone tell me how to draw an Ellipse using the CodeWorld package of Haskell? I want it to be like the rectangle function where I give two arguments for length and width. I have tried using solidClosedCurve-am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Using a closed curve, you can set the 4 vertices like so:

```
ellipse'(a, b) = closedCurve([(a,0),(0,b),(-a,0),(0,-b)])
```

Another way to do it is to say that an ellipse is a circle rescaled in one direction.

```
ellipse(a, b) = scaled(circle(1), a, b)
```

https://code.world/#Ps8tKc4KH4v8Z4iq91NZsew

Comment: Just FYI, the first example using `closedCurve` will be approximately an ellipse, but not exact.  To get a true ellipse, scaling a circle is the right way.